# Iterate and extract values from tables over multiple drop down lists

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table based on values from drop down lists from a web-page with multiple drop down lists (it requires login so I cannot post it here).

There are three drop down lists: `state`, `muni`, and `year`. Thus, there are very many tables I want to iterate and scrape through: `state * muni * year`.
I want to iterate and scrape through state (first), get muni (first), and all the years.
Then on the same state (first), get the next muni (second), and scrape tables from all the years:

```
state(1), muni(1), year(all)
state(1), muni(2), year(all)
            ... 
state(last), muni(last), year(all)
```

Pseudo-code:

```
for i in each unique state:
    select each muni
    for j in each muni:
        scrape each table from each year j in a year list
        append the year list in the muni list in a state list
```

I have done this so far, but it keeps iterating the years forever at the first state and muni, but doesn't move to the next one. Do you have any tips for how I can fix the issue? Any help is appreciated.

```
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

muni = []
year = []
data = []
for i in state:
    select_state = Select(browser.find_element_by_class_name("lists-landingpage--navigation-regionSelector"))
    select_state.select_by_value(i)
    options_muni = browser.find_element_by_class_name("lists-landingpage--navigation-subRegionSelector")
    options_muni  = options_muni.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    for j in options_muni:
        muni.append(j.get_attribute("value"))
        for k in muni:
            select_muni = Select(browser.find_element_by_class_name("lists-landingpage--navigation-subRegionSelector"))
            select_muni.select_by_value(k)
            options_year = browser.find_element_by_class_name("lists-landingpage--navigation-yearSelector")
            options_year = options_year.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
            for n in options_year:
                year.append(n.get_attribute("value"))
                table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'lists-landingpage--body'})
                table_body = table.find('tbody')
                rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
                for row in rows:
                    cols = row.find_all('td')
                    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
                    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

How can I append them in lists (`year`) in lists (`muni`) in a list (`state`)?

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Comment: @KunduK everything is behind a paywall, so I don't think it would be helpful for you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it to a list of dictionaries

```
all_data = []

for i in state:
    for j in options_muni:
        values = {'state': i, 'muni': j, 'years': []}
        for n in options_year:
            values['years'].append(options_year)
```

Example:

```
states = ['state1', 'state2', 'state3']
munis = ['muni1', 'muni2', 'muni3']
years = ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']
```

will output

```
{'state': 'state1', 'muni': 'muni1', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state1', 'muni': 'muni2', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state1', 'muni': 'muni3', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state2', 'muni': 'muni1', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state2', 'muni': 'muni2', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state2', 'muni': 'muni3', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state3', 'muni': 'muni1', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state3', 'muni': 'muni2', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
{'state': 'state3', 'muni': 'muni3', 'years': ['year1', 'year2', 'year3']}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be the final solution, when I am able to change my loop such that all those tables from states, munis and years are fetched